# Why does my WCF service occasionally hang on ((ICommunicationObject)channel).Close()?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm using the following code to create a channel from a ChannelFactory instance.  Everything is working as expected, but occasionally I'll get a 5-30 second hang on ((ICommunicationObject)channel).Close().  It doesn't happen every time Close() is called.  It happens when the factory is warm (i.e. already started) and when the factory is cold (i.e. first start).

What could be causing this?  I'm at a loss as to where I should start looking.

```
var channel = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
try
{
    ((ICommunicationObject)channel).Open();
    channel.UpdateEntities(serviceEndpoint, formEndpoint, departmentContextConfiguration);
    if (((ICommunicationObject)channel).State != CommunicationState.Faulted)
        ((ICommunicationObject)channel).Close();
}
catch
{
    ((ICommunicationObject)channel).Abort();
    throw;
}
```

The factory is created elsewhere using the following code:

```
_channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITCPVaultService>(new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress(uri.Uri))
```

Comment: 5-30 second hang with successful completion?  Or 5-30 second with a timeout or other exception thrown?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Successful completion.  Never times out.

Comment: Is it possible that "UpdateEntities" kicks off some kind of background thread or processing that is locking up the service?  Have you monitored the service at the time of the call?

Comment: From MSDN Docs: "The Close method allows any unfinished work to be completed before returning. For example, finish sending any buffered messages." I would try Fiddler or a related tool and see what it picks up. It sounds like there is some unfinished network activity.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I guess I need to brush up on my WCF documentation.  I incorrectly assumed that setting IsOneWay = True on the service contract method would result in proceeding without waiting for the process to finish.

Comment: @DerekW D'oh, beat my response by 15 seconds :-)

Comment: I was thinking it was an operation with `IsOneWay = true`. Gets a lot of programmers. :-)